# UML enumeration and class - how to connect

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

I'm trying to build a game in XNA (Space Invaders), but first I want to model it. I am using modeling in Visual Studio 2010. I first made a class called Invaders, and then an enumeration called InvaderType. Class Invader will use InvaderType so that each object coming from invader will be a specific InvaderType.

The thing I wanted to know is what to use to connect these two? The ones that seem logical are the association, composition, dependency, or connector. And when making a connection, should the class not automatically get the Enum type in its Attributes?

Comment: You wanted to answer but solely decided not too because I had no idea of how it works? Mmmm...

Comment: Anyways, now that I know you can answer me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´d just define an attribute "type" in class Invaders and indicate that the type of the "type" attribute is InvaderType

Comment: Got the "type" of InvaderType in the Invaders class - but shouldn't a line also be drawn?

Comment: Not when defining attributes. A line is used to indicate associations. It is possible to define an association between a class and a datatype/enumeration but it´s not usual (and the semantics would be the same as just defining the attribute)